# Clicking multiple images javascript not working

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make multiple images clickable  using javascript, so I have one div which has a big image and another div has smaller multiple images, if I click one of the multiple images it should change to a big image(obvious all multiple images to be clickable and change to a big image when clicked) now the problem is the images are not clickable and in console there is no errors, how can I make them clickable?

Here is code .

**blade**

```
  <div class="bigImage">
   @if(count($product->ProductsPhoto))
       <img src="{{ Storage::url($product->ProductsPhoto[0]->filename) }}"  style="width:400px;" alt=""  class="active" id="currentImage">
       @else
       <h1>no picture</h1>
       @endif
   </div>

  <div class="product-section-images">
      @foreach($product->ProductsPhoto as $product)
       <img src="{{ Storage::url($product->filename) }}" style="width:200px;" class="card-img" alt="">
       @endforeach
     </div>
   @endforeach
```

**Javascript**

```
   <script>
    (function(){
        const currentImage = document.querySelector('#currentImage');
        const images = document.querySelectorAll('.product-section-images');

        images.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener('click', thumbnailClick));

        function thumbnailClick(e) {
          currentImage.src = this.querySelector('img').src;
            currentImage.classList.remove('active');

            currentImage.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
                currentImage.src = this.querySelector('img').src;
                currentImage.classList.add('active');
            })

            images.forEach((element) => element.classList.remove('selected'));
            this.classList.add('selected');
        }

    })();
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `const images = document.querySelectorAll('.product-section-images');` needs to be `const images = document.querySelectorAll('.card-img');`. You are targeting images not it's parent div

Comment: That still not working @AlivetoDie

Comment: `this.querySelector('img').src` will always pick the first image from the div. Use `e.target.src` instead (with the tagName check to make sure an image was clicked). And attach the transition event outside of the click listener, currently you're adding a new listener on every click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring the wrong element in `querySelectorAll()`. Specify the *class* of the image element as part of the parameter. Since you are not passing `this` from the function, you will not get correct `this` inside the event handler function. You can pass `this` so that you can refer that inside the function. As arrow function (`=>`) does have its own `this`, you can replace that with the normal function syntax.

**Demo:**

```js
(function(){
  const currentImage = document.querySelector('#currentImage');
  const images = document.querySelectorAll('.product-section-images > .card-img');

  images.forEach(function(element){
    element.addEventListener('click', function(){thumbnailClick(this)})
  });

  function thumbnailClick(that) {
    currentImage.src = that.src;
    currentImage.classList.remove('active');

    currentImage.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
        currentImage.src = that.src;
        currentImage.classList.add('active');
    })

    images.forEach((element) => element.classList.remove('selected'));
    that.classList.add('selected');
  }

})();
```

```html
<div class="bigImage">
  <img src="/"  style="width:400px;" alt=""  class="active" id="currentImage">

</div>

<div class="product-section-images">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" style="width:200px;" class="card-img" alt="aa">
  
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/10/30/16/06/water-lily-3784022__340.jpg" style="width:200px;" class="card-img" alt="bb">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attaching `click` listener to  the `div` with class `product-section-images` and within the 
`thumbnailClick` function you are using `this.querySelector('img').src;`, where `this` is `div` and 
`querySelector` will `always` select first `img` and not clicked Image.

Instead attach click listener to the `images` using `document.querySelectorAll('.product-section-images img')` and within the `thumbnailClick` use `this.src;`, where `this` will be `clicked` image.

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.product-section-images img');  

images.forEach((img) => img.addEventListener('click', thumbnailClick));

function thumbnailClick(e) {
    currentImage.src = this.src; 
    currentImage.classList.remove('active');

    currentImage.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
        currentImage.src = this.querySelector('img').src;
        currentImage.classList.add('active');
    })

    images.forEach((element) => element.classList.remove('selected'));
    this.classList.add('selected');
}
```

Comment: Do I have to import anything because all these answers looks good but I have tried them all still not working, I don't know what's the problem @randomSoul

Comment: `Not working` is not really helpful. I would recommend go step by step. See if on click function is getting invoked or not.

Comment: Yeah I know that , that is why I have said all these answers looks like they work, sometime the problem may happen else where like javascript cdn or something.@randomSoul

Comment: Guessing something is not a good idea. I think you are displaying the clicked image in `<div class="bigImage"></div>`, within this `div` you have `if` condition `@if(count($product->ProductsPhoto))`, might be this condition is not evaluating to true.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind to use `Jquery`, then you can do this,

```
 $(".card-img").click(function() {
     let small_Image_Src = $(this).attr('src');
     $(".card-img.selected").removeClass('selected');
     $(this).addClass('selected');
     let big_Image = $("#currentImage");
     big_Image.attr('src',small_Image_Src);
     big_Image.addClass('active');
 });
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/vebayeyuye/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thank you guys  for your answers, all of them works fine.